# Cassandra With Spark connector - How Insert list Of Items to Cassandra

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Working with Cassandra and Spark 2.12 (3.2.0) with java.
Cassandra connector 3.1.0

My purpose fetch from s3 do preprocess and insert parallel into Cassandra.

I encounter with problem that I did preprocess on each s3 file that include list of items to insert to Cassandra which look like:  `JavaRDD<List<SearchEntity>>`

How should I pass it to cassandra (as in code example) ? I see it supports single object `mapToRow`.
maybe I miss something ?

Using the following code

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
        .setAppName("Example Spark App")
        .setMaster("local[1]")
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1");
        
    JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", "XXXX");
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "YYYY");
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "XXXXX");
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem");
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive", "true");
                
    JavaPairRDD<String, PortableDataStream> javaPairRDD = sparkContext.binaryFiles("s3a://root/folder/");
        
    File ROOT = createTempFolder().getAbsoluteFile();
        
    JavaRDD<List<SearchEntity>> listJavaRDD = javaPairRDD.map(rdd -> {
            System.out.println("Working on TAR: " + rdd._1);
        
            DataInputStream stream = rdd._2.open();
        
            // some preprocess
            List<SearchEntity> toCassandraList = new WorkerTest(ROOT, stream).run();
        
            return toCassandraList;
        });
        
    // here I want to take List<SearchEntity> toCassandraList and save them
    // but I don't see how as it support only single object ..
    CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(listJavaRDD)
        .writerBuilder("demoV2", "simple_search", 
                       CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(List<SearchEntity> list objects ...)) // here is problem
        .saveToCassandra();
        
    System.out.println("Finish run s3ToCassandra:");
    sparkContext.stop();
}
```

The schema was configured before manually only for tests purposes.

```
CREATE TABLE simple_search (
    engine text,
    term text,
    time bigint,
    rank bigint,
    url text,
    domain text,
    pagenum bigint,
    descr text,
    display_url text,
    title text,
    type text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((engine, term), time , url, domain, pagenum)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY 
  (time DESC, url DESC,  domain DESC , pagenum DESC);
```

Both Java and Scala solutions are welcomed

Comment: what is the table schema? I don't think that you have a table consisting only of the list of entries. Also, what is the reason for not using DataFrame API instead of RDD?

Comment: Thanks @Alex Ott , It is binary tar files I want to load it from s3 on folder level with "/", didn't find any example how use DataFrame , the tar are huge also i need to merge some content file after extracting the tar and convert them to Pojo list for cassandra (the tar schema is folders/files hierarchy when it untared)  . Regarding the schema and KEYSPACE I create it manually before but will share here in question (Btw, the bulk insert works with simple cassandra java api pretty well) , i wonder how can i do it with spark.

Comment: If you can convert it to DataFrame for best practices will be great :)

Comment: and `SearchEntity` is matching to the table by structure? Because the first thing that you'll need to do is `flatMap` - convert `RDD<List<SearchEntry>>` into the `RDD<SearchEntry>`. Also, what version of Spark Cassandra Connector?

Comment: Yes SearchEntity exactly fit to structure (it works with basic java cassandra connector).  <version>3.1.0</version>          <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.12</artifactId>. Can you share how to flat it ?. Also it won't hits the performance to open for each JavaRDD - SearchEntry , as now I have millions of SearchEntry items ...

Comment: Success to convert like - JavaRDD<SearchEntity> newRdd =  listJavaRDD.flatMap(List::iterator);

  CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(newRdd)
    .writerBuilder("demoV2", "simple_search", CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(SearchEntity.class))
    .saveToCassandra();   // is it correct approach of flating it, what about paralleling ? again I have millions of entities

Comment: yes, that's correct, but you can simplify it. `flatMap` on RDD will be executed on the workers... Let me write this as an answer

Comment: Found this link to be useful. - https://www.cloudwalker.io/2019/01/29/spark-cassandra/

Answer (score 0):

To write the data, you need to work on the `SearchEntity`, not on the list of the `SearchEntity`.  To do that, you need to use `flatMap` instead of ordinary `map`:

```java
JavaRDD<SearchEntity> entriesRDD = javaPairRDD.flatMap(rdd -> {
        System.out.println("Working on TAR: " + rdd._1);
        DataInputStream stream = rdd._2.open();
        // some preprocess
        List<SearchEntity> toCassandraList = new WorkerTest(ROOT, stream).run();
        return toCassandraList;
    });
```

and then you can just write the as per [documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/7_java_api.md#example-of-saving-an-rdd-of-person-objects-to-a-cassandra-table):

```java
javaFunctions(rdd).writerBuilder("demoV2", "simple_search",
   mapToRow(SearchEntity.class)).saveToCassandra();
```

P.S. But be beware, that if your tar is too big, it may cause memory errors on the workers, when you're creating the `List<SearchEntity>`.  Depending on the file format inside tar file, it could be more optimal to unpack data first, and then read them using Spark.

Comment: unpack data on disk ? I have millions of tars a lot of IO, maybe do you familiar with some java/scala library that i can use directly to fetch files by name from tar.gz in memory ?

Comment: commons-compress may help. My comment was generic - it all depends from many factors

Comment: your answer this not working, I got compilation error. what I can do instead is: JavaRDD<SearchEntity> rddList = javaPairRDD.map(rdd -> {
   DataInputStream stream = rdd._2.open();
   System.out.println("Working on TAR: " + rdd._1);  //  but i'm not sure it is better

   List<SearchEntity> listItem = new WorkerTest(ROOT, stream).run();

   return listItem;
  }).flatMap(List::iterator);

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it’s a difference between Scala and Java. My answer could be just modified to return iterator()…